# Vue.js - Dynamic buttons with dynamic v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm generating some menu buttons dynamically (not sure if that's best practice)

script

```
items: [
{ title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/' },
{ title: 'Register', icon: 'mdi-image', route: '/register' },
{ title: 'Login', icon: 'mdi-help-box', route: '/login' },
],
```

html

```
<v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" link :to="{path: item.route}">
```

But what I want to do is hide the dashboard button until they have signed in. The user signed in value is kept in store.

```
$store.state.user.signedIn // true/false
```

How can I programmatically hide buttons depending on signed in value? I was trying to do this

```
{ title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/', reqAuth: true }
```

But not sure how to get it working smoothly in the html. I'd also like to do the reverse later on the login/register buttons, if the user IS signed in then these should hide and a Logout button will come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` property should be defined as computed property and add `shown` field in each item of items and use state value as its value in dashboard link :

```
computed :{
 items(){
const signedIn=$store.state.user.signedIn; 
  return  [
      { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/', shown:signedIn },
      { title: 'Register', icon: 'mdi-image', route: '/register',shown:!signedIn},
      { title: 'Login', icon: 'mdi-help-box', route: '/login' , shown:!signedIn},
]
  }
}
```

in template add

```
<v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" link v-if="item.shown" :to="{path: item.route}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- **A)** have separate menu arrays and display one or the other based on `isLoggedIn`. If you have any items showing in both cases, you'll need to place them in a third array and concat one of the first two with the third
- **B)** have a boolean property on each menu item stating whether it should show when `isLoggedIn` or not. If you have menu items showing on both, you'll need either two props on each item (`showWhenLoggedIn`, `showWhenLoggedOut` - change them if too long) or, alternatively, you could make the `show` an array of booleans: `show: [true, false]` - first bool controlling whether it's shown when logged out, second when logged in).

Solution **A)** example (separate arrays):

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    loggedInMenuItems: [
      { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/', show: [false, true] },
    ],
    loggedOutMenuItems: [
      { title: 'Register', icon: 'mdi-image', route: '/register', show: [true, false] },
      { title: 'Login', icon: 'mdi-help-box', route: '/login', show: [true, false] },
    ],
    permanentMenuItems: [
      { title: 'Terms and Conditions', icon: 'mdi-whatever', route: '/terms', show: [true, true] }
    ],
    isLoggedIn: false
  }),
  computed: {
    menuItems() {
      return (this.isLoggedIn
        ? this.loggedInMenuItems
        : this.loggedOutMenuItems
      ).concat(this.permanentMenuItems)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label><input v-model="isLoggedIn" type="checkbox"> Is logged in</label>
  <pre v-html="menuItems.map(m => m.title)"></pre>
</div>
```

Solution **B)** example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard', route: '/', show: [false, true] },
      { title: 'Register', icon: 'mdi-image', route: '/register', show: [true, false] },
      { title: 'Login', icon: 'mdi-help-box', route: '/login', show: [true, false] },
      { title: 'Terms and Conditions', icon: 'mdi-whatever', route: '/terms', show: [true, true] }
    ],
    isLoggedIn: false
  }),
  computed: {
    menuItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => item.show[Number(!!this.isLoggedIn)])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label><input v-model="isLoggedIn" type="checkbox"> Is logged in</label>
  <pre v-html="menuItems.map(m => m.title)"></pre>
</div>
```

I personally prefer the second one, for brevity. I also find it a tad more elegant.

However, in large teams or in projects where code complexity needs to be kept to a minimum and code readability to a maximum, the first solution is often times preferred.

Lastly, second solution allows more flexibility for menu items order, although it's not a real issue (implementing an `order` attribute to each item would be trivial).

---

*Note:* obviously, `isLoggedIn` should come from state, not from component data fn. I placed it in `data` so you could easily test it here.